# NTFS format (mkfs) -- which areas of the disk get overwritten?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, data-recovery, ntfs

I accidentally ran `mkfs.ntfs -Q /dev/sda` (instead of `/dev/sda6`) on a 2Tb external HDD. Luckily, there's a 1G unused partition at the beginning, and also plenty of space at the end:

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048    2099199    2097152    1G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2  *       2099200 3739256831 3737157632  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       3739256832 3907029166  167772335   80G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       3739258880 3751841791   12582912    6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       3751843840 3907029166  155185327   74G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Is `/dev/sda2` safe? Or does mkfs.ntfs write metadata in the middle of the target space, in which case I guess *any* file could be corrupted without so much as a warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is `/dev/sda2` safe?

In general: no. Keep reading to learn why I think so.

---

#### Example procedure

My 2TB HDD is of the size 2000398934016 bytes. The goal is to investigate what `mkfs.ntfs -Q` would do to a device of this size.

I create a sparse file of this exact size:

```
$ # the filesystem must support sparse files
$ truncate -s 2000398934016 fakesda
```

`ls -ls` confirms the whole file is sparse:

```
$ ls -ls fakesda
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 2000398934016 Oct 31 18:48 fakesda
```

(the first `0` tells this). But also [`sparsemap`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395051/108618) (which will be useful later) does:

```
$ sparsemap fakesda
HOLE 2000398934016
```

I could do `mkfs.ntfs -FQ fakesda`, but then `mkfs.ntfs` would assume the sector size is 512 bytes. In this example let's assume my disk uses 4096 bytes as its logical sector size. In such case I think I can use `--sector-size` option of `mkfs.ntfs` (see `man 8 mkfs.ntfs`). But to be sure what sole `mkfs.ntfs -Q` would do to my disk I decide to create a loop device from `fakesda`:

```
$ sudo losetup -f --show --sector-size 4096 fakesda
/dev/loop0
```

`sparsemap` tells me `fakesda` is still completely sparse. I run `mkfs.ntfs -Q` on the loop device:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs -Q /dev/loop0
```

I destroy the loop device and `sync` just in case:

```
$ sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
$ sync
```

How sparse is the file now?

```
$ sparsemap fakesda
DATA 12288
HOLE 4096
DATA 110592
HOLE 250049753088
DATA 61460480
HOLE 750088122368
DATA 67125248
HOLE 1000132341760
DATA 4096
```

See `sparsemap -h` to learn how to interpret this

> The file is interpreted as a sequence of data and holes, for example
> given a file with 8192 bytes of data followed by a 4096 byte hole followed
> by 8192 bytes of data the output of sparsemap would be:
>
> ```
> DATA 8192
> HOLE 4096
> DATA 8192
> ```

In my result each `DATA` line denotes a fragment affected by `mkfs.ntfs`. **I can see `mkfs.ntfs` *does* write something in the middle of the target space.**

Finally I remove the file with `rm fakesda`.

---

#### Your specific case

You can do your own tests using the exact size (and sector size) of your disk and the same `mkfs.ntfs` you used. This way you will probably be able to identify affected fragments accurately and to tell which partitions (which old filesystems) they belong to. Mapping the fragments to particular files or metadata in your old filesystems may not be easy and it's a different issue.

The partition table you posted tells me the sector size is 512 bytes in your case. I think you can use `mkfs.ntfs -FQ fakesda` without playing with `losetup`. My example deliberately uses different sector size, this way the answer is more general.

---

#### Doubt

If `mkfs.ntfs -Q` writes zeros to some part of the file it operates on, and if it's smart enough to achieve this by sparsifying the file, then my procedure won't detect this. Frankly I don't know if the tool does it. If it does then you need something more than my procedure to find *all* the affected fragments.

This imperfection of the procedure does not change the conclusion: the filesystem in your `/dev/sda2` may have been partially overwritten.

I note `mkfs.ntfs` without `-Q` actually writes zeros *without* sparsifying the file; in fact it desparsifies the whole file. I tested this with files way smaller than 2TB, but still. I can only *suspect* `mkfs.ntfs -Q` is similar and never sparsifies the file.

---

#### Notes

- My testbed: Debian GNU/Linux 10.
- My `mkfs.ntfs -V` prints `mkntfs v2017.3.23AR.3 (libntfs-3g)`.
- I installed `sparsemap` by

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python3-pip
  sudo pip3 install sparseutils
  ```